# In clause in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

```
var Charts = chartGroup
     .Descendants("charts")
     .Elements("chart")
     .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == chartId.ToString())
     .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
```

Here I want to use an "in-clause"" (like the `in` clause in SQL) for `Attribute("id").Value` for array of strings:

like:

```
Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value in ("1","2")
Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value` in charIds[]
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: If you are not using plain LINQ to objects, you have to keep in mind that some `IQueryable` providers don't implement all the constructs you throw at them (like `Contains`). Newer versions of pretty much all ORM frameworks will handle this, but in older ones you'd have to hack some SQL yourself. Of course, this looks like it's working on plain CLR objects.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have a set of values in an array, then you can use:

```
.Where(x => charids.Contains(x.Attribute("id").Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Contains method of IEnumerable:

```
var ids = new[]{"1", "2"};
Where(x=>ids.Contains(x.Attribute("id").Value));
```

**update:**

moreover, this code will transfer in 'in' statement in SQL for IQueryable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
var ids = new []{"id1","id2", ... };
var Charts = chartGroup.Descendants("charts")
                       .Elements("chart")
                .Where(x =>  ids.Contains(x.Attribute("id").Value))
                .Select(x => x.Attribute("name").Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL `Where – In` Functionality can be easily achieved by Lambda Expression.
SQL query -

```
Select Name,Id from Category Where Id In (71,72)
```

Lambda Expression –

```
List checkedRecords = new List { 71, 72 };
var Cs = Context.Categories.Where(c => checkedRecords.Contains(c.Id));
```

I Hope this would help.

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` in LINQ is `Enumerable.Contains` or `Enumerable.Any`. Here are several approaches:

```
string[] strIDs = new[]{ "6", "7" };
int[] intIDs = new[]{ 1, 2 };
char[] charIds = new[]{ '4', '5' };

....
.Where(x => strIDs.Contains(x.Attribute("id"))
     || intIDs.Any(i => i.ToString() == x.Attribute("id"))
     || charIds.Any(c => c.ToString() == x.Attribute("id")));
```

Answer (score 0):

something like ... where charIds.Contains(x.Attribute"id".Value)

Answer (score -1):

```
var memberData = (from u in _objGroupRepositoty.Value.GetUsers()
                                         join umedia in _objGroupRepositoty.Value.GetMediaDetails() on u.userid equals umedia.userid
                                         join gm in _objGroupRepositoty.Value.GetGroupMaster() on groupId equals gm.GDID
                                         join m in _objGroupRepositoty.Value.GetGroupMembers() on u.userid equals m.userid
                                         join media in _objGroupRepositoty.Value.GetMediaDetails() on gm.GDID equals media.GDID

                                         where (m.GDID == groupId
                                         && m.IsActive == true
                                         && gm.IsActive == true
                                         && u.IsActive == true)

                                         select new
                                         {
                                             userid = u.userid,
                                             firstname = u.firstname,
                                             lastname = u.lastname,
                                             mobile_no = u.mobile_no,
                                             imagepath = umedia.media_path,
                                             IsAdmin = m.IsAdmin,
                                             GroupID = gm.GroupID,
                                             group_name = gm.group_name,
                                             tagline = gm.tagline,
                                             groupImage = media.media_path,
                                             ChatRoomId = gm.ChatRoomId,
                                             OperationType

                                             //newMember = newMemberLists.Contains(u.userid) than "Y" : "N",
                                         }).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: please try adding some explanation and details to your answer that would be helpful